# Warping a control from attached example

Tags: html, css, asp.net, telerik

Can anyone please show me how to create a design box like in the attached linked
I have the control that actually uploading the files but I want the design that warping it.

[Upload Files to Azure](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/file-upload-to-amazon-s3-azure/defaultcs.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the demos site from your Telerik account and examine the code. There are a couple of CSS classes used and an image. The dev toolbar of the browser can tell you the rest.